# AngularJS send data from controller to another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, controller

Hello Guys I want to send the $scope.test data to use it in my other controller "FormCtrl"
And in $scope.content is an id and many other objects and in $scope.test is also an id i want to use both data at the same id ... but more important is to get the scope.test data to use it in FormCtrl... greez

```
var app = angular.module('surveyApp', []);

app.controller('BackendCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    var apiURL = "JSON DATA";
    var apiURL2 = "DIFFERENT JSON DATA";

    $http.get(apiURL).then(function(response) {
      $scope.content = response.data;
    });

    $http.get(apiURL2).then(function(response) {
      $scope.test = response.data;
    });

  });


app.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope, $http) {



      $scope.formData = {};
      $scope.formData.id = $scope.a.id;

      $scope.formData.checkbox = "1";
      $scope.formData.textarea = $scope.a.id;

      $scope.save = function(formData) {
          $scope.submitFormData = angular.copy(formData);


         $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'update.php',
            data: $scope.submitFormData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });


      };
});
```

Comment: use angular service

Comment: I recommend that you post the data as `'Content-Type: application/json` if the API accepts that.

Comment: @georgeawg thx mate

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your hierarchy is built. Let's assume you want to use data from BackendCtrl in your FormCtrl. If your FormCtrl sits inside of your BackendCtrl, like so:

```html
<div ng-controller="BackendCtrl">
...
<div ng-controller="FormCtrl"></div>
...
</div>
```

then the FormCtrl inherits all of it's variables. You could call them just like they were in the scope from FormCtrl, because they actually are:

```js
var app = angular.module('surveyApp', []);

app.controller('BackendCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.myVariable = "foo";
});


app.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log($scope.myVariable); // logs "foo"
});
```

---

If your Controllers are siblings, like so:

```html
<div ng-controller="BackendCtrl"></div>
...
<div ng-controller="FormCtrl"></div>
```

your only clean option is to inject `$rootScope` and broadcast your needed variables down to all child scopes.

```js
var app = angular.module('surveyApp', []);

app.controller('BackendCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope){
    $scope.myVariable = "foo";

    $rootScope.$broadcast('broadcastEvent', $scope.myVariable);
});


app.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.$on('broadcastEvent', function(event, broadcastedVariable) {
        // optional: $scope.myVariable = "foo";
        console.log(broadcastedVariable); // logs "foo"
    });
});
```

---

If your FormCtrl is the parent of BackendCtrl, like so:

```html
<div ng-controller="FormCtrl">
...
<div ng-controller="BackendCtrl"></div>
...
</div>
```

then you have to emit the data from your BackendCtrl and then use it in FormCtrl:

```js
var app = angular.module('surveyApp', []);

app.controller('BackendCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope){
    $scope.myVariable = "foo";

    $scope.$emit('broadcastEvent', $scope.myVariable);
});


app.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.$on('broadcastEvent', function(event, broadcastedVariable) {
        // optional: $scope.myVariable = "foo";
        console.log(broadcastedVariable); // logs "foo"
    });
});
```

---

But it's not recommended to make use of the last two options, because that would miss the point about the whole scope and controller thing. If you want to access data in a controller from another controller that isn't it's parent, the best way to do it is actually make it it's parent OR of course define the data in a newly created parent controller of both.

Comment: thank you !! but what if i dont use ng-repeat for $scope.test .. how can i use the data like  x in test, x.name of id of $scope.content which i have used in ng-repeat..

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. Where in your question is an ng-repeat? And what are you even talking about?